# Block of integers: Divisibility

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $a < b$ be natural numbers. Prove that every block of $b$ consecutive natural numbers contains two distinct elements whose product is divisible by $ab$. **(I've proved this)**

Suppose now $a < b < c$ are natural numbers: prove that every block of $c$ consecutive natural numbers contain three distinct elements whose product is divisible by $abc$?

**Attempt to the second part:**

I'm trying to relate the case of two numbers in the first part. I can find two distinct numbers in the "$c$-block" such that their product is divisible by $ac$ or by $bc$. Problem is now getting this third distinct number, in particular I want to form the "$ab$" product. I've tried looking at a "$b$-block" within that "$c$-block" but I haven't been able to come up with a proof.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt.

Since the block is of size $c$, there is only one number which is divisible by $c$. Since $b<c$, there is "at least one" number (can be 1 or more) which is divisible by $b$. Again $a<b$, So for every block $b$ you choose (by dividing the $c$ block into many partitions so that each partition contains exactly one number divisible by $b$ and all the numbers in it are consecutive), so there is "at least one" number in every partition which is divisible by $a$. Thus, we can select three different numbers whose product is divisible by $abc$.

Comment: When there is a `<` outside math mode (stuff enclosed in `$` signs) or backticks (grave accents) - ``thus: `<` `` - the HTML parser thinks it's the start of a HTML tag, and thus the following stuff isn't rendered. That's why originally only the start of your answer was visible. Will Orrick edited and enclosed your inequalities in `$` signs so that it's the MathJax parser that deals with them (and that interprets `<` as a less-than sign, as it was intended).

Comment: Well lets say there is only one number in the list that is divisible by b say m, which is also divisible by c, so this number is a multiple of their lcm. Now also bc doesn't divide this number. We can use first part to show there is a n s.t. m and n are distinct and ab divides mn.

Comment: Now with a, you can consider every a-block in the c-block but it can also be the case that there is only one multiple of a on the list and this is the same number as above i.e. we have a number divisible by a,b,c but not divisible by abc. Now we can use the the first part again to get another number p that is distinct and ac divides mp. But this product is $m^2pn$.

Comment: As we know their lcm isn't simply their product, we also know the numbers aren't co-prime. From here on I'm stumped. The other cases are easy to show it is true. It seems you have made the problem seem rather more trivial than what it actually is.